# Which authentication server to use on company for Single Sign-On (SSO)?

Tags: open-source, authentication

I need to find an open source authentication server to use [Single Sign-On (SSO)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) in the company where I work.

We have several web sites and several mobile application. And we need to centralize the authentication for our users and then use SSO.

We think that we will use SAML or OpenID, we haven’t take a decision about that yet.

Do you have advice for the architecture and the authentication server to use?